# Replace keys with values in a Hash

Tags: ruby

What is the best way to replace all keys with values in a hash?
I came up with:

```
Hash[hash.map {|k,v| [v,k]}]
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Be careful when doing this. A hash's keys must be unique, but values don't have to be. When you invert the hash the duplicate values will collide, overwriting each other, with the last one winning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to `invert` a hash:

```
{ 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2 }.invert # => {1=>"a", 2=>"b"}
```

But be careful of the side-effects:

```
{ 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 2 }.invert # => {1=>"a", 2=>"c"}
```

A hash's keys must be unique, but values don't have to be. When you invert the hash the duplicate values will collide, overwriting each other, with the last one winning.

Answer (score 5):

There's a built-in method for that:

```
 hash.invert
```